# Angular2 nested ngFor. Is nested expressions possible?

Tags: angular, expression, ngfor

I'm trying to use a value in an expression binding.  I know this isn't valid but want to know if something similar is possible.  If not, is there another way to go about it.

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
selector: 'Home',
templateUrl: './views/home/home.html'
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit{

    rows = [
       { 'FirstName': 'John', 'LastName': 'Doe' },
       { 'FirstName': 'Ashley', 'LastName': 'Doe' }
    ];

    cols = [
       { 'Desc': 'First Name', 'Data': 'FirstName' },
       { 'Desc': 'Last Name', 'Data': 'LastName' }
    ]; 
}
```

home.html

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th *ngFor="let col of cols">{{col.Desc}}</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tr *ngFor="let row of rows">     
    <td *ngFor="let col of cols">
      {{row.{{col.Data}}}}     
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Never nest `{{}}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use it like this:

```js
{{ row[col.Data] }}
```

In Javascript you can access every property via `obj.propName` AND `obj[propName]`, too!